# Windows 7 bitlocker no TPM - don't want USB - are multiple partitions with unencrypted system partition an option?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, bitlocker

I have a Windows 7 laptop without TPM chip --- have checked BIOS and machine spec - definitely no TPM chip :-(

I need to run bitlocker. I understand that without TPM chip I can use a USB key at boot to run the computer, but I really don't want to do this.

My question is can I partition my SSD to give (say) C:\ and D:\ and put all the potentially sensitive stuff on D:\ and bitlock D:\ and store the key on C:\ - unencrypted system partition?

.... I suppose a related question is 'does the USB key give access to the bitlock encrypted drive - or does it also need a password'

So my plan is to partition the SSD then encrypt the non-OS partition to store data.
* Is this possible?
* Is it sensible?
* Any thoughts?
Many thanks in advance!
p.s. I am happy to look up the web to find out how to repartition and turn on bitlocker - but I can't find anything about this particular overall strategy.

Comment: No; If you want to use Bitlocker you will need to use the USB Key.

Comment: @Ramhound I can understand this if the whole HDD is going to be encrypted - but not if only part is going to be encrypted....

Comment: @Ramhound - I have just done this and it works with password and no USBkey... see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been able to create a data partition (in my case I chose T:) and I have copied my 'sensitive information' to it and it is now bitlocked with password protection and no need to use USB key and I have no TPM chip...

... the proceedure was

1) check there is enough space on the harddrive (or SSD)

2) defragment the harddrive (or SSD)

3) create new data partition

4) put the information on the new partition and delete it from the old one

5) open windows explorer so that you can see the new data partition

6) right click on the partition and turn on bitlocker and follow the instructions.

... so it turned out to be really easy in the end.

I post the answer here because after a fair bit of websearching it was not clear to me if it would be possible to use bitlocker on a computer that did not have a TPM chip - so from my experience it is possible to do this and have the data partition just protected by a password. (other spec Windows 7 (pro edition I think))

Oh I did use a USB key to store the recovery information, but I do not need to use that everytime I want to access the drive - only the password - and the recovery information is just there incase I forget the password...

**Final edit**

I have just used the same method on a computer with TPM chip - worked in the same way, simple password protection for the sensitive data partition.